# Problem with mysql root password

Tags: mysql, password, root

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. What is my mysql root password? If I enter

```
mysql -u root -p
```

It asks me to enter a password: I don't know it, and no password won't work either. Mysql was pre-installed, so I didn't choose any root password. If I try to install it again, with

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

It says that mysql-server is already the newest version (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)

Any help, hints? Thanks.

Comment: this link has all in it-> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

First is purging mysql(only if you don't already have a database):

Use

```
apt-get purge mysql-server
```

to purge and then

```
apt-get install mysql-server
```

to simply reinstall it. While installing it should ask you for a password. This is the easiest and fastest way, however it could come to problems if some programs like phpmyadmin already connected to the existing MySQL so I'd suggest you to use the

Or do the following: Stop the MySQL Server using

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Then start the safe mode with

```
sudo /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

Select localhost as host(After the last command there won't be a command prompt, so after the message `Starting mysqld daemon with databases from [...]` type in the next command)

```
mysql -h localhost
```

select mysql with

```
USE mysql
```

*(Replace YOURNEWPASSWORD with your new password!)* Type

```
UPDATE mysql.user 
SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('new_password') 
WHERE user='root' AND host='localhost';
```

Exit with

```
quit
```

And restart MySQL with

```
sudo mysqladmin shutdown 
sudo service mysql start
```

**Edit**

That error has something to do with your MySQL socket. First you want to find all socket files on your system with:

```
sudo find / -type s
```

Your socket should be something similar to this

```
/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

(important is the `/mysql.sock` part)

Once you find where the socket is being opened, add or edit the line to your

```
/etc/my.cnf
```

file with the path to the socket file:

put

```
[mysqld]
```

at the very beginning and

```
socket=/path/to/your/socket/
```

at the very end of the file.

*Try the 2. option again now. If it doesn't work continue with this explanation.*

If this doesn't solve your problem something overrides the my.cnf location, and that would result in a socket not being found where the my.cnf file indicates it should be. Then when you try to run the mysql command line client, it will read my.cnf to find the socket, but it will not find it since it deviates from where the server created one. So, Unless you care where the socket resides, just changing the my.cnf to match should work.

To fix this start with shutting down the `mysqld` process

```
pkill -9 mysqld
```

After you do this you might want to look for a pid file in /var/run/mysqld/ and delete it

Make sure the permissions on your socket is such that whatever user mysqld is running as can read/write to it. An easy test is to open it up to full read/write and see if it still works:

chmod 755 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Sources:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html

https://ubuntu.flowconsult.at/en/mysql-set-change-reset-root-password/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq

Comment: When I try to log in as root (step 3 of option 2) it says -- ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
[1]+  Exit 1 -- is it ok?

Comment: @A.N.Other edited my answer a bit

Comment: I see only /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock in the socket list with mysql in their name...That's a bit different from the one you suggest...If you think that's ok, I'll go forward with your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: It's okay. I only said something similar.

Comment: I put the new line with the path into the /etc/mysql/my.cnf. Then, after the "skip-grant-tables" it says: mysqld: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line 23!
mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted! -- there is also a mysql.cnf.d dir that contains other .cnf files... mysqld.cnf  mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf
 -- Should I edit them all?

Comment: Did you use your own path or that written in my command?

Comment: My own path: here's all my non-commented "my.conf" file: !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

socket=/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Comment: Since this goes a bit too far for commenting I'd ask you to join this chat room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/61431/discussion-with-a-n-other?tab=general

Comment: Done that finally, thank you so much, and thanks to all who answered

Answer (score 4):

For the new **my-sql** 5.7 if password is left empty then it uses auth_plugin.

In that case login with `sudo` privilege.

```
$ sudo mysql -u root -p
```

After login you can simply use this to update password.

```
$ ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'new-password';
```

For complete refrence check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51862084/5957834).

**EDIT**:
One can also use this (without `-u root`):

```
$ sudo mysql
$ ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'new-password';
```

Comment: It works also without the option `-u root` he chooses automatically root. And you can leave the option `-p` out. You just need to enter the sudo password, no mysql-root password

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL 5.7, the default password is printed in the logs.
A quick grep can return it.

```
grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

References:
https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/05/18/where-is-the-mysql-5-7-root-password/

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991228/what-is-the-default-root-pasword-for-mysql-5-7

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127537/setting-root-password-in-fresh-mysql-5-7-installation

Comment: grep: /var/log/mysqld.log: "No such file or directory". I have /var/log/mysql and then "error.log       error.log.2.gz  error.log.4.gz  error.log.6.gz
error.log.1.gz  error.log.3.gz  error.log.5.gz  error.log.7.gz"

Comment: Try it on /var/log/mysql/error.log, then. It's just a different log name. Do any of the files around there come up with an answer? The file that you're logging to is likely somewhere in the conf file for MySQL which should be somewhere like "/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf"

Comment: With 'temporary password' none, if i grep 'password' there is:  'Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password' and 'Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password', but no actual password

Comment: I would do a quick "zgrep temporary *" in that dir and if that turns up nothing, follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33563395/5990780) to by-pass the access rights and set a new root password.
Further detailed resetting instructions are [on the MySQL  docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: All the info  is actually distribution-dependent, and at this stage I am at a loss on what to do in my case. I wonder if anyone who wants to try mysql on Linux has to go through all of this?!?!

Comment: I could do that on OSX following this guide:  https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-change-the-mysql-root-password/ ....But

sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop

In Ubuntu it says command not found when I try to stop it...

Answer (score 0):

**UBUNTU 16.04 and MYSQL 5.7.20**

I did not find ADDB's instructions completely helpful. After searching I discovered the following (a small re-write for Option 2):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
    sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld/
    sudo chown mysql /var/run/mysqld/
    sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
    mysql -uroot
    use mysql;
    update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("NEW_PASSWORD_GOES_HERE") where User='root';
    flush privileges;
    quit;
    sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
    sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Reference: http://rricketts.com/reset-root-password-mysql-5-7-ubuntu-16-04-lts/

My preferred method:

I used the Mysql user "debian-sys-maint" (a root equivelant).  The password can be found in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf.  After logging into Mysql as this user change the password for any Mysql user.

```
USE mysql
SELECT root@localhost;
ALTER USER user IDENTIFIED BY 'auth_string';
ALTER USER 'Name_of_user_to_be_modified'@'Hostname (ie:localhost)' IDENTIFIED BY 'NEW_PASSWORD';
flush privileges;
exit;
```

Reference: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/9948/what-is-the-debian-sys-maint-mysql-user-and-more